# Plugin Repository commit doesn't show up in activity

Tags: plugins, svn, repository, review

I've just published the first update for one of my WordPress plugins but I'm not sure if it was successful. I had a few errors in previous attempts to commit to the SVN repository, so I tried it with a utility called `SmartSVN`, which says that the commit was successful, but I can't find it in my WordPress Repository account, even though I can find it in my SVN logs:

```
$ svn log
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1591738 | xxxxxx | 2017-02-08 14:19:48 +0100 (Wed, 08 Feb 2017) | 1 line

Version 1.1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1539256 | xxxxxx | 2016-11-23 18:07:57 +0100 (Wed, 23 Nov 2016) | 1 line

Version 1.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1537938 | plugin-master | 2016-11-22 01:26:11 +0100 (Tue, 22 Nov 2016) | 1 line

adding xxxxxx-payments-woocommerce by xxxxxx
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it just up for review and can't I see the status? I can't see a review request on the 'Add your plugin' page:

[image: empty request page]

My activity overview also doesn't shed any light:

[image: empty activity]

Should I just assume that it's under review?

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin is already in the repository, you don't need to submit the form to ADD a new plugin, you only need to update the trunk folder to make your update via svn.

Sure WordPress will send you an email to tell you that the name is already use by another plugin and ask you to change its name.

When updating a plugin, WordPress doesn't care about it, you can make update in the trunk folder and push the older one in the related tags folder that you need to create.

Don't forget to update the readme.txt to tell WordPress repository which version to serve to users and modify the main plugin file accordling to this value.

i.e : if you want the trunk folder to be be last version, readme.txt must contains `stable version: trunk` and the main plugin file `version: 1.1`.
In the tags folder, add a folder 1.0 where the version 1.0 need to be copy.

Hope its helps.